# UWP and iOS json parsing comparison

Tags: ios, json, performance, parsing, uwp

We are trying to port ipad application to UWP. which is heavily relayed on json parsing which is huge(json data) coming from the server ~2 - ~4 mb.

In iOS, parsing is handled using dictionary and built in serialize and deserialize methods.
Where as in UWP, we use Newtonsoft, ***TryGetValue*** for each of the json key to store in a property/object.

When i compare the performance with iOS app and UWP app on a device. UWP is taking 50% more time than iOS.

Is this an issue in UWP/.NET??

Thanks in advance,
Rummy

Comment: How are you parsing data in UWP?? show us some code

Comment: private async Task<CrewDetails> ExtractDataAsync(dynamic item) {
            try
            {
                JToken value;
                CrewDetails crewDetails = new CrewDetails();

                if (item.TryGetValue("ID", out value))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                    {
                        crewOnBoardDetails.Id = (int)value;
                    }
                }Catch(Exception ex){}